# How do I reset a column to its default in a sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a mysql table using the code:

```
CREATE TABLE `slide_patch_features` 
(
    `patch_feature_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `patch_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `patch_feature_file_path` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`patch_feature_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `IDX_slide_patch_features_01` (`patch_id`),
    KEY `FK_slide_patch_features_slide_patch` (`patch_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_slide_patch_features_slide_patch` FOREIGN KEY (`patch_id`) REFERENCES 
    `slide_patch` (`patch_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I filled out the table. Now I want to reset just one column say 'patch_feature_file_path'. How do I do that?

I do not want to drop the entire table and create a new one as the other columns are useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

update slide_patch_features set patch_feature_file_path = null

Comment: I get an error: You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect

Comment: You need to provide the database type you are using (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) to answer that problem.  For example, for MySQL, you need to execute this statement before the UPDATE: SET sql_safe_updates = 0;

Answer (score -2):

I ended up dropping and then re-adding my column:

## drop column

ALTER TABLE slide_patch_features DROP COLUMN patch_feature_file_pathpatch_feature_file_path

## add column

ALTER TABLE slide_patch_features
ADD COLUMN patch_feature_file_path varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL AFTER patch_id;